# Android: setting maxHeight parameter programmatically for ProgressBar/SeekBar

Tags: android, view, progress-bar, seekbar

One can create a SeekBar in XML as follows...

```
<SeekBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/bpseekbar"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
      android:max="100"
      android:maxHeight="8dp"
      ...
```

Now I want to do this programmatically since I need to adjust maxHeight based on screen resolution (yes, I know one shouldn't do that, but I have my valid reasons for this). I have no problems with setting the parameters programmatically except that I can't find out how to set maxHeight. I feel like I need to use Attributes but I couldn't find exactly how. Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not directly possible. SeekBar (actually ProgressBar which SeekBar extends) gets maxHeight only from XML layout attributes, there's no corresponding method.

Additionally, ProgressBar increases its maxHeight in call to setProgressDrawable to be at least height of the drawable. You may utilize this.

Another possibility is to extend SeekBar and provide own onMeasure method. This is actually where maxHeight is used. You can then use your extended SeekBar in xml layout.

Comment: so if i subclass seekbar. override onmeasure, and pass max(mymax,onmeasureheight)as height to super it should work?

Comment: Override maxheight?? Depends on what you mean.

Comment: It should. Check Android's source of ProgressBar.onMeasure and see how mMaxHeight is used, then use your max height value similarly.

Comment: create a custom seekbar and then use it

Comment: I ended up writing my own SeekBar class that inherits from View

Answer (score 1):

The best way to set the maxHeight of seekBar programmatically is to use the fourth constructor `SeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)`, follow steps below:

1. define a style in values/style.xml;

```xml
    <style name="SeekBarDefaultStyle">
        <item name="android:maxHeight">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:mirrorForRtl">true</item>
    </style>
```

2. construct the SeekBar like this: `mSeekBar = new SeekBar(context, null, 0, R.style.SeekBarDefaultStyle);`

BTW, google decides to support the method of setMaxHeight in API 29: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setMaxHeight(int)